# How to fadeout borders and bgcolour of a div after some time of pageload?

Tags: jquery, css, onload, fadeout

i want to show this div "abc" on page load. at that time suppose background colour will be yellow. and borders will be black. but after few seconds there will be only the text. no borders and bgcolour.

```
<script>
$(window).load(function(){
    setTimeout(function(){
        $('#abc').fadeIn();
        $('#abc').fadeOut();
    },1000);
});
</script>

<div id="abc"  style="background-color:#FFFF99; border:1px; border-style:solid; border-color:#000000;">
Hello, i want to stay, i don`t my borders and bg.
<div>
```

Comment: it 's works, [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/7kmfbtpm/2/)

Comment: no.. it's not ,, it fades out the whole div. i just want to hide the border and bgcolour....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like a great use for CSS3 'transition' property if you want to keep the 'fade' effect but not fade out the div itself.

jQuery:

```
setTimeout(function(){
    $('#abc').fadeIn();
    $('#abc').addClass('noHighlight');
},1000);
```

CSS:

```
#abc {
   background-color:#FFFF99; 
   border:1px; 
   border-style:solid; 
   border-color:#000000;
   transition:all 1s;}

#abc.noHighlight {
   background:transparent;
   border-color:transparent;}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="abc">
     Hello, i want to stay, i don`t my borders and bg.
<div>
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/rh11wgw5/

Comment: i'd use css solution as like in this answer, Also it tells inline styles are generally bad. +1

Answer (score 1):

so, this is your want?  [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/7kmfbtpm/4/)

```
    setTimeout(function(){
      $('#abc').fadeIn();
      $('#abc').removeAttr('style');
    },1000);
```